# Fantasy anime with blond male who lives with his female senpai

Tags: story-identification, anime

I really want to know the name of this anime that I saw some time ago, but I did not save it in my anime list and now I can't find it.

It had a blond main character. He must do an exam. There is more than one exam, but in one of them they must go over a bridge and I think there was something to do with gold in the dirt. Another exam was in some village, where they must have some money. The main character was helping villagers with changing things with them. The anime had 2 seasons, I think. I am certain that it was about a male, with blond hair to his shoulders and a mark on his face. It was a fantasy anime, and the main character has a female *senpai* (roughly, an upperclassman who provides guidance) who teaches him how to control his powers. There were some magic items too. One of the exams was in snow. I know that my description is bad, but I only can remember little things.

The blonde main character can use a sword, I think. He lives with his female *senpai* in a forest, maybe regular trees or maybe bamboo; I really do not know.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't know if my correction is better or worse. I changed the words more.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question)

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - I always try my best to preserve as much of the original wording, even if I end up moving it around the page.

Comment: That's fair. :-P Too many years of punching up essays for people. I tend to correct things even where there's a chance they weren't incorrect in the first place.

Comment: I really thank you. I am not english speaking person so...And I dont know where to ask in my country(there isnt something like this "forum?" meaby? So I must go there, but I think that my english is not that much bad..Yeah I know it is bad:D:D

Comment: @FantasyAria You may want to register your account, and follow [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge the unregistered and registered accounts. Then you should be able to comment on your question, and accept an answer once one is posted.

Comment: @FantasyAria Please follow the instructions to merge your accounts so you can comment on and edit your question. Welcome to [scifi.se]!

Answer (score 4):

I am pretty sure it is the anime called [*Reikenzan*](https://myanimelist.net/anime/32094/Reikenzan__Hoshikuzu-tachi_no_Utage)

[image: Image of the main character]

The main character show above fits the description in the question quite perfectly.

> am certain that it was about a male, with blond hair to his shoulders and a mark on his face

In the anime he also lives with his senpai, which is girl. All the exams are also fitting to the anime, that's the first season. (It has, as you mentioned, 2 seasons so far)